# PHP MYSQL удалить файлы которые не скачивались уже месяц

Tags: php, mysql

Есть сайт файлообменник, со следующей структурой бд:

```
UPLOADS:
id | dir | name | active | timestamp

DOWNLOADS:
id | file_id | timestamp
```

Нужно получить `id.uploads` файлов  которые не удалены `active = 1` у которых не было ни одного скачивания в таблице `downloads` за последний месяц.

Корректно ли это сделать следующим запросом?

```
SELECT dir, name FROM uploads AS u JOIN downloads AS d ON d.file_id = u.id WHERE 
u.active = 1 AND u.timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND d.id NOT
IN(SELECT id FROM downloads WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
GROUP BY u.id
```

Логика запроса:

> Получить id из uploads которые active = 1 и id которых нет в file_id 
>   записей в таблице  downloads добавленных за последний месяц.

Можно так же сократить запрос:

```
SELECT dir, name FROM uploads WHERE active = 1 AND timestamp < 
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND id NOT IN(SELECT file_id FROM downloads 
WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую практический такой же запрос для аналогичного назначения. Ещё могу посоветовать другой способ, добавляете в таблицу `uploads` поле `lastupdate` и при скачивании его обновляете. И таким образом можно из таблицы файлов сразу получать активные/неактивные записи, исходя из даты последнего запроса к ним.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал какой-то из этих вариантов:

```
//Left Join
SELECT u.id, u.dir, u.name
FROM uploads LEFT JOIN downdoads d
ON u.id=d.id
WHERE u.active=1 AND d.timestamp>DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND d.id IS NULL

//EXISTS
SELECT u.id, u.dir, u.name
FROM uploads 
WHERE u.active=1 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM downdoads d WHERE u.id=d.id AND  d.timestamp>DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY))
```

Но нужно смотреть план запроса, что будет быстрее работать.

Comment: Не совсем понял как работает второй вариант `NOT EXIST`? Он возвращает  список ID которых не существует в `download`?

Comment: в поздапросе ищем записи в download за последние 30 дней. `NOT EXISTS` означает, что такой записи существовать не должно, соответственно, он подходит под условие и ее можно удалять